# Testing angularjs directive generating html code or not

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a directive something like this which I want to test,

```
.directive('gridHeader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        compile: function(tEle, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
            var h3 = tEle.find('h3');
            var temp = h3.html();
            temp = temp.replace('xxxx', tAttrs.gridHeader);
            h3.html(temp);
        },
        template: '<div class="grid-header">' +
            '<h3>Showing {{grid.data.records}} xxxx</h3>' +
            '<div class="pull-right">' +            
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
            '</div>'
    }
})
```

I have tried something like this, but its not working

```
  it('directive: should generate all required html elements', function() {
      var items = angular.element('div.grid-header');    
      console.log(items.length);    //always returning 0
      expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: Assuming you've assigned `element = $compile('<div grid-header></div>')(someScope)`, you should be able to check `expect(element.hasClass('grid-header')).toBeTruthy()`

Comment: I am just compiling but not assigning it to some element

Comment: Well you should if you want to check the compiled HTML

Comment: Where and how are you compiling your directive? could you update the code in question? -ah never mind, just saw you solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of checking directive HTML in unit tests (I feel that's better suited in e2e) however something like this should suffice...

Save a reference to the compiled element

```
var element;

...

inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.grid = { data: { records: 'records' } };

    element = $compile('<div grid-header="foo"></div>')(scope);

    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Then you can run tests against it

```
it('whatever', function() {
    expect(element.hasClass('grid-header')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(element.find('h3').text()).toEqual('Showing records foo');
});
```